# How to include php variable url?

Tags: php, variables, include

Currently, as an example, I have this php code on one of my pages.

```
<?php include("codes/games/scripts/titles/angrybirds.php"); ?>
```

How would I change this to make my variable:

```
$gametitle = "angrybirds";
```

work like this:

```
<?php include("codes/games/scripts/titles/$gametitle.php"); ?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code should work as-is, since the `.` won't be interpreted as part of the variable name. You can see the output of it here: http://codepad.org/ZbtiOPgB

However, for readability, I would encourage you to either use clear concatenation:

```
<?php include("codes/games/scripts/titles/".$gametitle.".php"); ?>
```

Or wrap your variable name(s) in `{` and `}`:

```
<?php include("codes/games/scripts/titles/{$gametitle}.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php include('codes/games/scripts/titles/'.$gametitle.'.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
<?php include('codes/games/scripts/titles/'.$gametitle.'.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$file = 'codes/games/scripts/titles/' . $gametitle . '.php';

if (file_exists($file))
    require_once($file);
?>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the game title is dynamic user input, which is why I suggest using `file_exists()`, so that if the game title is phony it won't throw errors.